# Hibernate @ManyToMany uses only FK from owning table to remove entries in connection table

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, many-to-many

I have `@ManyToMany` relationship of `Author` and `Source` entities, where `Author` is owning entity. When I remove author everything is OK and hibernate generates `Hibernate: delete from author_source where author=?`. But when I remove source, Hibernate generates same query for each occurrence of `authorId` in `author_source` table which had connection with deleted source. So this query also removes connection between other sources (if author had two sources, both connections are removed).

Author entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "author")
public class Author implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "authorId")
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer authorId;

    @SourceFormat // own formatter 
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "author_source",
            joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "author") },
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "source") }
    )
    private Set<Source> sources;
}
```

Source entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "source")
public class Source implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "sourceId")
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer sourceId;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "sources")
    private Set<Author> authors;
}
```

I want Hibernate to generate

```
delete from author_source where author=?
```

query when I remove author, and

```
delete from author_source where source=?
```

when I remove source. Is it possible or should I do it manually?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to define the join table in both entities.

Make sure that the joinColumn and the inverseJoinColumn are opposites on the opposing sides of the relation.

- joinColumn on one side == inverseJoinColumn on other side
- inverseJoinColumn on one side == joinColumn on other side

.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "author")
public class Author extends Serializable {

  ...

  @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @JoinTable(name="author_source",
        joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="author_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="source_id")
  )
  private Set<Source> sources;

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "source")
public class Source extends Serializable {

  ...

  @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @JoinTable(name="author_source",
        joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="source_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="author_id")
  )
  private Set<Author> authors;

}
```

Comment: Are you sure about `CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN`? It just removes all sources which don't have connection with any author. (tried with `@Cascade(CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN)`)

Comment: Kurochenko: isn't it what you want to achieve ? When you remove an author, all sources associated with this author will become orphans and will be removed. However, when you remove a source and the author has other children sources, then the author won't be removed, which is what I though was your requirement.

Comment: Well, no. I've probably explained id wrongly. When I remove author, Hibernate removes from author_source according to author_source.author (and leaves source table untouched). Its OK. But when I remove source, it also removes from author_source according author_source.author, not according to author_source.source (see aforementioned generated SQL command). This may lead to unwanted removal of connections between authors and other sources.

Comment: Sorry, now I understand what you mean. I modified my proposition accordingly.